# PowerBI Tile issue IOS

Tags: javascript, html, ios, powerbi

I'm using PowerBI REST to make an iOS App. Image below shows the result. When I click on any of the tiles I get no response, while if I click **ON** the red border (added in photoshop) Page respond to the click only if the tile includes a map, other tiles still no response.

Running the same page in a browser on Mac everything works, but on an iOS device it doesn't.

HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    // listen for message to receive tile click messages.
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
    } else {
        window.attachEvent("onmessage", receiveMessage);
    }

    //The embedded tile posts messages for clicks to parent window. Listen and handle as appropriate
    function receiveMessage(event) {
        messageData = JSON.parse(event.data);
        if (messageData.event == "tileClicked"){
            window.webkit.messageHandlers.callbackHandler.postMessage(messageData.navigationUrl.toString());
        }
    }


    function updateEmbedReport() {
            var w = window.innerWidth - 25;
            var h = window.innerHeight;

            // check if the embed url was selected
            var embedUrl = "";

            var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe1');
            iframe.src = embedUrl;
            iframe.onload = postActionLoadReport;
            iframe.height = h;
            iframe.width = w;

    }

    function postActionLoadReport() {
        // get the access token.
        accessToken = ;

         var w = window.innerWidth - 25;
         var h = window.innerHeight;

        // construct the post message structure
        var m = { action: "loadTile", accessToken: accessToken, height: h, width: w};
        message = JSON.stringify(m);

        // push the message.
        iframe = document.getElementById('iframe1');
        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(message, "*");
        iframe.height = h;
        iframe.width = w;
      }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="updateEmbedReport()">
<iframe id="iframe1" width="250px" frameBorder="0" name="iframe1" height="250px" style="cursor:pointer"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Swift code (which I use to make the app respond to tile click)

```
private var mWebView: WKWebView?
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    let mWebViewConfig: WKWebViewConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
    mWebViewConfig.userContentController.addScriptMessageHandler(self, name: "callbackHandler")
    mWebViewConfig.preferences.javaScriptEnabled = true
    mWebViewConfig.preferences.javaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true
    self.mWebView = WKWebView(frame: self.frame, configuration: mWebViewConfig)
    //self.mWebView!.scrollView.scrollEnabled = false
    self.addSubview(self.mWebView!)
}

func setData(url: String, tileClick: ITileClick){
    self.mTileClick = tileClick
    let page: String = (InstanceReferences.mPowerBIHandler?.GetPage(InstanceReferences.mAuthenticationToken!, EmbedURL: url, ReportPage: false))!
    self.mWebView?.loadHTMLString(page, baseURL: NSURL(string: url)!)
}
func userContentController(userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceiveScriptMessage message: WKScriptMessage) {
print("iniside")
if message.name == "callbackHandler" {
    self.mTileClick?.OnTilePageClick("\(message.body)")
}   }
```

**Note: Used the same HTML page in android app and everything is working without issues.**

[image]

Any help would be great.

Comment: how have you managed to get tiles to display? Whenever I try passing reports into a WKWebview all that is returned from PowerBI is "This content isn't available" Are there certain settings that you need to pass in the WKWebview to make it render?

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to use any of the drill down options using the Power BI App on iphone?

Comment: I don't know, I never tried their iPhone app. I'm building a custom app which will also include PowerBI

Comment: The drill down functionality doesn't work correctly on the iphone app

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug in the embedded page which prevents it from detecting iOS taps. I believe you won't be able to solve this on your end due to cross-domain restrictions.

You can workaround this problem by saving the navigation URL provided to you by the tileLoaded event (fired on tile load), and detecting taps in iOS (Using a gesture recognizer on the WKWebView).

Comment: TileLoaded event will provide me with NavigationURL for the report? When we click on the tile we get the navigation url of the report the tile is part of

Comment: You should get the same navigation URL (usually the report) on the tileLoaded event.